# how to load angular images from a folder outside root folder in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, buffer, assets

I'm using angular 4 and I have an image folder with 1Gb size! when I put this folder in the assets folder and run ng build I get the error of `RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed` can I put this folder outside my angular project and load the images from there? I don't know how to prevent that error and load images from somewhere outside angular project!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve 'RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed' when running ng serve or ng build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270563/how-to-solve-rangeerror-array-buffer-allocation-failed-when-running-ng-serve)

Comment: @ShashikantDevaniI got no answer there and I thought if I can move the images or not!

Answer (score 0):

you can put your images in the cloud(google drive ...) and you use the cloud's link to access on the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your approach of loading the images from assets of such huge size. You should query your images from your backend application. Your assets folder should contain  any of css, js, fonts, image files. In images folder I prefer to have logos, background images etc.
To your question -- You can though configure assets folder in angular-cli.json under "apps": [{"assets": "assets", "favicon.ico"}]. This might help you https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration
If you succeed in moving the image file your ultimate dist folder will become quite large and it will affect your performance and user experience largely